# Is there an upper bound on $||MN+NM||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For two non-zero (generally complex) matrices $M$ and $N$, how to find the upper bound on the quantity $||MN+NM||$ where $||\cdot||$ is the Frobenius norm?

Comment: If you do not put any restrictions on $M,N,$ "the" (only) upper bound is $+\infty.$

Comment: Naively you might think $||MN+NM|| \le 2 ||M||\, ||N||$

Comment: Thanks, @Henry. How to prove this?

Comment: @AnneBauval, I want $M$ and $N$ to be finite.

Comment: Mike, they are finite. That is not sufficient for "the" upper bound not to be $+\infty.$ And if you fix $M,N$ then "the" (least) upper bound is $||MN+NM||$ itself. So, your question needs some clarification before being reasonably answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You have $||A+B|| \le ||A||+||B||$ from the triangle inequality

and $||AB|| \le ||A||\,||B||$ as  the Frobenius norm is sub-multiplicative (a Cauchy–Schwarz inequality result)

so (assuming $M$ and $N$ are square): $||MN+NM|| \le ||MN||+||NM||\le 2 ||M||\, ||N||$